# Implement VSCode snippet for C++ header guard

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I tried to create a snippet in VSCode to quickly include C++ header guards. For example with a file path is `C:\workspace\src\chrome\browser\ui\webui\settings\about_handler.h`

The snippet is expected to generate like this:

```cpp
#ifndef CHROME_BROWSER_UI_WEBUI_SETTINGS_ABOUT_HANDLER_H_
#define CHROME_BROWSER_UI_WEBUI_SETTINGS_ABOUT_HANDLER_H_

#endif // CHROME_BROWSER_UI_WEBUI_SETTINGS_ABOUT_HANDLER_H_
```

From [VScode snippet syntax guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-syntax), I tried to use `TM_FILEPATH` variable but cannot find a solution to transform the filepath into the macros above. I tried some way below:

- with the transform `${TM_FILEPATH/([^a-zA-Z0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9])/${1:+_}${2:/upcase}/g}_` I can generate the filepath into `C__WORKSPACE_SRC_CHROME_BROWSER_UI_WEBUI_SETTINGS_ABOUT_HANDLER_H_`. This regex will convert all non-digit and non-alphabetic characters to `_` and change all alphabetic characters to upper case.
- with the transform `${TM_FILEPATH/.*src[\\\\\\/](.*)/${1:/upcase}/}` I can generate into `CHROME\BROWSER\UI\WEBUI\SETTINGS\ABOUT_HANDLER.H`. This regex remove the path from begining to `src` since my current workspace is in `src` folder so I want my header macro to be related to that.

The problem is I cannot combine these two transform to get the macro I want. Is there any ideas to make it works?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I already upvoted your answer before

Comment: So, it did not work, right? Do you need any more help with this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, your solution works flawless

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```js
"CppGuard": {
        "prefix": "cppgrd",
        "body": [
          "#ifndef ${TM_FILEPATH/(?:^.*\\\\src\\\\)?(\\w+)(?!\\w*$)|(\\W)|(\\w+)$/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}${3:/upcase}${3:+_}/g}",
          "#define ${TM_FILEPATH/(?:^.*\\\\src\\\\)?(\\w+)(?!\\w*$)|(\\W)|(\\w+)$/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}${3:/upcase}${3:+_}/g}",
          "\n#endif // ${TM_FILEPATH/(?:^.*\\\\src\\\\)?(\\w+)(?!\\w*$)|(\\W)|(\\w+)$/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}${3:/upcase}${3:+_}/g}"
        ]
      }
```

The command is

```js
${TM_FILEPATH/(?:^.*\\\\src\\\\)?(\\w+)(?!\\w*$)|(\\W)|(\\w+)$/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}${3:/upcase}${3:+_}/g}"
```

[image]
See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J3eQYM/1).

**Details**

- `(?:^.*\\src\\)?(\w+)(?!\w*$)` - an optional occurrence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible from the start of string (`^.*`), up to the `\src\` substring (`\\src\\`), then one or more word chars captured into Group 1 (`(\w+)`), that are not followed with end of string (`(?!\w*$)`)
- `|` - or
- `(\W)` - Group 2: any non-word char
- `|` - or
- `(\w+)$` - Group 3: one or more word chars at the end of string.

The replacement means:

- `${1:/upcase}` - inserts Group 1 value turned to uppercase
- `${2:+_}` - if Group 2 was matched, insert a `_`
- `${3:/upcase}`  - inserts Group 3 value in upper case
- `${3:+_}` - if Group 3 matched, inserts a `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"cppHeaderGuard": {
  "prefix": "g1",
  "body": [
    "#ifndef ${TM_FILEPATH/(?:^.*\\\\src\\\\)?(\\w+)\\W?/${1:/upcase}_/g}",
    "#define ${TM_FILEPATH/(?:^.*\\\\src\\\\)?(\\w+)\\W?/${1:/upcase}_/g}",
    "",
    "#endif // ${TM_FILEPATH/(?:^.*\\\\src\\\\)?(\\w+)\\W?/${1:/upcase}_/g}"
  ]
}
```

[image: cppGuard snippet demo]

The trick is to get everything you are interested in, the text between the path separators and the final `.`, into one capture group if you can.  That is pretty easy in your case using a non-capturing group and a final bit that isn't captured:

`(?:^.*\\\\src\\\\)?(\\w+)\\W?`

But you do want all that **matched** so that vscode's snippet engine will replace it.  In this case, the replacement is dead simple:

`${1:/upcase}_`

Every full match, like `chrome\` will be replaced by capture group 1, e.g., `chrome`, capitalized and an underscore.

Since you actually want an underscore at the end that makes it easy too - you don't need any conditional logic to determine whether there is a capture group at the very end that shouldn't be followed by an underscore.

Comment: I did not use `(?:^.*\\src\\)?(\w+)\W?` pattern on purpose (I certainly tested it, too). This pattern assumes there are no consecutive special characters which is usually true for this kind of input, but still we cannot be too sure of it. I decided to keep my pattern as generic as possible.

Comment: Ahh, then as usual the nature of the input, in this case a file path, will determine what special cases need to be considered.